# keep getting: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, switch-statement

Hi i'm still new to java and i'm trying to make this program to calculate exchange rates. There is a problem with which i don't seem to get out. I keep on getting this message: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException. Can somebody help me. I'm trying to read a number and a word in a text file.

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> import java.io.*;
> import java.text.*;
>
> public class Main {
>   public static final double dollarNaarEuro = 1*0.74;
>   public static final double yenNaarEuro = 1*0.071;
>   public static final double pondNaarEuro = 1*1.21;
>   public static final double oreNaarEuro = 1*0.11;
>
> public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
>
> File f = new File("test.txt");
> if (f.exists() && f.isFile()) {
> Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
>
> sc.useDelimiter("\\s*  \\s*");
> while (sc.hasNext()
> ) {
> String s = sc.next();
>
> String s1 = sc.next();
> double geld = Double.parseDouble(s1);
> s = s.replace("$", "Dollar");
> s = s.replace("E", "Euro");
> s = s.replace("Y", "Yen");
> s = s.replace("B", "British Pound");
> s = s.replace("O", "Ore");
>
>   System.out.println("Deze bedragen staan in de file:"+s);
> /*  int geld = 1;
>
>         switch (geld) {
>             case 1:  System.out.println("Dollar"); break;
>             case 2:  System.out.println("Euro"); break;
>             case 3:  System.out.println("Yen"); break;
>             case 4:  System.out.println("British Pound"); break;
>             case 5:  System.out.println("Ore"); break;
>
>         }
>
>
>
> }*/
> sc.close();
>
>
> }}
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?

Answer (score 2):

You have one call of `sc.hasNext()` and 2 sequential calls of `sc.next()`.

```
String s = sc.next();
String s1 = sc.next();
```

The second call obviously causes exception when the last element has been read by the first call.

Answer (score 1):

You call `Scanner.next` twice in quick succession - once to set the variable `s` and a second time to set the variable `s1`.  If there isn't another string to read you'll get a `NoSuchElementException` as described in the JavaDoc  for [Scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29).

It doesn't look like you use the second variable so either remove it or protect it with a [Scanner.hasNext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
String s = sc.next();
double geld = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works now for the first part. Now i can keep on going with the rest.

> ```
>     import java.util.*;
> import java.io.*;
>
> public class Main {
>  public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
>  File f = new File("test.txt");
>  if (f.exists() && f.isFile()) {
>  Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
> sc.useDelimiter("\\s* \\s*");
> while (sc.hasNext()) {
>  String s = sc.next();
>
>      s = s.replace("$", "Dollar");
>      s = s.replace("E", "Euro");
>      s = s.replace("Y", "Yen");
>      s = s.replace("B", "British Pound");
>      s = s.replace("O", "Ore");
>
>
> System.out.println(sc.next() +" "+ s);
>
> }
> sc.close();
> }}
> }
> ```